# using reflection with dot42 project

Tags: c#, android, reflection, dot42

I am using dot42 with vs2010. i tried to get the list of fields for a class. i got 0 element in the list of fields.

Does dot42 support reflection?

any example or help will be appreciated.

best regards

Comment: Can you post your code please ?

Comment: It says it does: http://docs.dot42.com/Reference/M.System.Type.GetFields().  Show us what's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of what i am doing:

```
public class Class1
{
        public int publicInt;
        private string privateString;

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public void Method1()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

I have anthor class with generic method:

```
public class Class2
{
    public void GenericMethod<T>() where T : new()
    {
            Type entityType = typeof(T); 

        //Here, i want to get the FieldInfo list of T.
        //typeof(T) does not work also.
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity, when i click on a button i have:

```
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
 c2.GenericMethod<Class1>();
```